# PHPのソースコードをアップロードした際に反映されない場合がある理由が知りたいです

Tags: php, apache

Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (centos)
PHP Version:8.1.18
設定ファイルの内容などは全て同じ

■疑問のきっかけｋ
PHPで開発する際にサーバーを二つ立てています
一つは開発用テストサーバー（以後T）、一つはユーザー用サーバー（以後：U）です。
Uにソースコードを反映させる前にTでテストします。
しかし、Tで問題がないとUにアップロードしても反映されず
ブラウザキャッシュをクリアしてもOSやhttpdやphp-fpmを再起動しても反映されませんが
php artisan clearをすると反映されました。（動作は問題ありませんでした）
T→アップロードすれば即反映される
U→アップロード後キャッシュをクリアしなければ反映されない

■何が知りたいのか
何故アップロード先のサーバーが違うだけで手順を変えなければ反映されない自体が発生するのか。
対処法はどんなものが考えられるか。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Laravel の開発でしょうか、artisanコマンドがLaravelのキャッシュ機能のコマンドなのでサーバーが違えばキャッシュも違うと思います。